# Disable C# optimization of loop return value

Tags: c#, .net, jit, csc

I have a method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. I call this method form two places, and in one of those places I do not do anything with the results.

It looks like the C# compiler removes the call to that method even if I decorate it with `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]`. The code doesn't even enter the calling method. If I add `.ToList()` at the end, though, it is executed.

Is there a way to disable this optimization by the compiler/runtime? Looking at the ILDASM output, it looks like it's more of a runtime optimization because the call is there.

Comment: What does the method look like? If you use `yield` the resulting enumerable is evaluated lazily.

Comment: It sounds like the method is returning a lazy `IEnumerable<T>` using the `yield` keyword.  Adding `.ToList()` forces the `IEnumerable<T>` to be buffered and the method to be executed. This is very much a feature, not a bug!

Comment: I am in fact using a yield keyword. I agree it's a feature. I was just wondering if there's a way to "disable" it. Guess the best one is to not use lazy for this particular method?

Comment: It is not an optimization. Disabling it would change the flow of execution.

Comment: If lazy evaluation results in unexpected behaviour then you probably shouldn't be using it. It sounds like you should buffer the results in a list/array before returning.

Comment: Thanks guys. You are right, I should not be using lazy evaluation. The evaluation of the method has to happen even if the caller is not aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It looks like the C# compiler removes the call to that method

No, it doesn't - this is just how iterator blocks work. The code inside the iterator block will only start being executed when `MoveNext()` is called for the first time. If you want to make sure that the whole method gets executed, you could just use:

```
SomeIteratorMethod().Count();
```

That will iterate over the whole sequence, throwing away results as it goes (as opposed to a call to `ToList` for example, which will

If you only want to get as far as the first `yield` statement, you can use

```
SomeIteratorMethod().Any();
```

If you want *some* code to always execute (e.g. parameter validation) but then the rest should be lazy, you need to split the method in two methods:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> SomeIteratorMethod(string mustNotBeNull)
{
    if (mustNotBeNull == null)
    {
        throw ...
    }
    return SomeIteratorMethodImpl(mustNotBeNull);
}

private IEnumerable<Foo> SomeIteratorMethodImpl(string mustNotBeNull)
{
    ... yield new Foo()...
}
```

Or you could just stop using an iterator block, of course.